# Making my NSSecureTextField trigger an NSButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstextfield

I have an NSSecureTextField. How can I make it so that when the 'Enter' button is pressed on the keyboard, the 'login' button is triggered? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a better idea to just set the keyboard equivalent of the Login button itself to `\r`(return). To do that, select the button in Interface Builder, open the attributes inspector, and click in the `Key Equiv.`popup button, then press the `return` key so that it looks like the image below:

[image]

This will give the button the blue/graphite color making it the "default" button. Whenever the `return` or `enter` key is pressed, this button will be "clicked" automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this function.  Set the delegate of the NSSecureTextField to this function.
It will execute when you hit enter in the NSSecureTextField.

```
- (IBAction)control:(NSControl*)control textView:(NSTextView*)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{

    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:))
    {

        //Do login stuff
    }
    else if(commandSelector == @selector(deleteBackward:)){
        NSUInteger length = [[secureText stringValue] length];

        if(length != 0) 
        {
            [secureText setStringValue:[[secureText stringValue] substringToIndex: length-1]];
        }
    }

}
```

Found example [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1454.html)

EDIT:
Added a deleteBackward case to handle backspace since this function ignores backspace.